# Which package do I need for TACL template?

Tags: fonts, errors, templates, font-metrics

I've downloaded the following files from http://www.transacl.org/submission/ and placed them in the same directory:

```
acl2012.tex
acl2012.sty
acl2012.pdf
acl.bst
```

but when i tried to compile the .tex file, it doesn't compile and I've got this error in my log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/media/alvas/E418A6B618A686E0/tacl/.acl2012.tex.swp
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 10 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)) (./acl2012.sty
Conference Style for ACL 2005 -- released Octobe 11, 2004
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
No file .acl2012.tex.aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
/media/alvas/E418A6B618A686E0/tacl/.acl2012.tex.swp:35: Font OT1/ptm/m/n/10.95=
ptmr7t at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.35 \begin{document}

/media/alvas/E418A6B618A686E0/tacl/.acl2012.tex.swp:35:  ==> Fatal error occurr
ed, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on /tmp/.acl2012.tex.log.
```

**Am I missing some packages?
What is `Metric (TFM) file`? 
How do I resolve the errors?**

I've tried reinstalling/updating my `texlive` too but it didn't work:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive-latex-base is already the newest version.
texlive-latex-extra is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: I'm afraid your TeX distribution is incomplete. Try reinstalling `texlive-latex-base`

Comment: That hasn't reinstalled it. apt-get has just told you you already have the newest installed. Either pass an option to force it to reinstall or uninstall first and then install. I don't have apt-get on this machine as it isn't Debian-based but apt-get --help or man apt-get should explain the options available. A TFM is a TeX Font Metric. It tells TeX which characters a font has, how big they are and how to adjust the spaces between different characters. What does locate ptmr7t give as output?

Comment: i'm pretty noob to latex, what should i do to `locate ptmr7t`??

Comment: @2er0: I assume you are on Linux. That's not a TeX-specific command. Just open a terminal emulator e.g. gnome-terminal or konsole or xterm or anything (wherever you type sudo apt-get...) and just type 'locate ptmr7t' (without quotes) as a command in the shell. Alternatively, see if texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/times/ptmr7t.tfm exists beneath your main texmf tree. That might be e.g. /usr/share/texmf/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/adobe/times/ptmr7t.tfm or similar. (I'm not sure /usr/share/texmf will be right - I don't know where Debian installs it - but it should be something like that.)

Comment: `locate ptmr7t` returns nothing =(

Comment: @2er0 Did you take egreg's advice? You need to tell your package manager to reinstall even if it thinks everything is already up-to-date. It probably doesn't know you are missing stuff for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested that style file and works for me on this laptop. I have complete 2012 TeXLive installed on OpenBSD 5.4. It works both via

```
latex->latex->bibtex->latex->dvips->ps2pdf
```

and

```
pdflatex->pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex
```

routine. Few warnings but nothing major.